# HTTP/2 support for iOS 8

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, http2

I tried Xcode 7 Beta + NSURLSession, which already supports HTTP/2 and it works just amazing.

Now I'm wondering, when I release the app built with iOS 9 SDK but with iOS 8 support - will iOS 8 users be able to use HTTP2 ?
Or it will only work for iOS 9 ?

Comment: Nope, HTTP/2 is iOS 9 only!

Comment: That's what I also heard, but would be nice to have some proof links

Comment: As you can see in the [Networking with NSURLSession slides on page 35](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/711y6zlz0ll/711/711_networking_with_nsurlsession.pdf?dl=1) HTTP/2 is marked `NEW`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Apple Developers Forum and they gave a crystal clear answer:

> The HTTP/2 support is part of iOS 9, and thus won't be available on
>   earlier OS releases.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/31667

> But what is bothering me is iOS 8 behaviour. I'm still confused by
>   your actual issue.  I suspect you're talking about this case:
>
> 1. you build an app using NSURLSession
> 2. you deploy a server that supports HTTP/2
> 3. on iOS 9, this will talk to your server via HTTP/2
> 4. on iOS 8, this will talk to your server via HTTP/1.1 or SPDY
> 5. on iOS 7, this will talk to your server via HTTP/1.1
>
> Whether this works really depends on your server.  Ignoring iOS 8 and
>   SPDY for the moment, consider the iOS 7 case.  Here iOS is simply
>   going to open the connection and send an HTTP command.  What does your
>   server do in that case?  It should handle it correctly, but iOS can't
>   guarantee that.
>
> OTOH, if I read your original question literally, you seem to be
>   asking about this case:
>
> 1. you build an app using NSURLSession
> 2. you deploy a server that supports HTTP/2
> 3. on iOS 9, this will talk to your server via HTTP/2
> 4. on iOS 8, will it send HTTP/2 requests?
>
> The answer here is no: the HTTP/2 support is part of iOS 9, and thus
>   won't be available on earlier OS releases. OTOH, iOS 8 does have
>   support for SPDY.  See WWDC 2014 Session 707 What's New in Foundation
>   Networking for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
HTTP/2 supported by iOS 9 + NSURLSession.
```

NSURLConnection is deprecated.